# Visual Studio 2012 distribution file issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, installshield

I used Visual Studio 2012 and created an installation file with the Installshield Limitied edition like below.
[InstallShiled Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YadJH.png)
By the way, it is installed in windows 10 but not in windows7.
And the error message is shown like below. 
 "Current processor type does not support the installation package.Please contact the product vendor"
If you have any advice on the above problem,please let me know. thank you!!

Comment: is your Windows 10 32 bits ?

Comment: 64 bit is in use. thanks

Comment: In InstallShield, what is set in General Information -> Template Summary ?

Comment: Your problem is that it doesn't install on Windows 7 ? If so, is the Windows 7 32 or 64 ?

Comment: it's weird... i can't find Template Summary in General information....it doesn't support visual studio 2012?

Comment: it is the Windows 7 32. thanks.

Comment: Your package is targeting a x64 OS, that's why you can't install it on a 32 bits windows 7

Comment: Thank you for your confirmation. Is there any other solution??

Comment: Change project setting an uncheck the x64 option.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! i will try it.